# How to prevent deleting a FireFox Local Storage value?

Tags: firefox, youtube, local-storage

For an example, I have this `yt-player-quality` value for www.youtube.com  domain in my firefox local-storage which saves the visitor's youtube player quality.

The value has set to:
`{"data":"medium","expiration":1538035321798,"creation":1535443321798}`

which means next time I play a youtube video, it loads with quality 360p
(possible values are: `large`=`480p`,`medium`=`360p`, `small`=`240p`, `tiny`=`144p`)

I want to freeze it's value to `large` in my browser. So even If I delete my browser data, It always load the quality 480p.
I don't like always logged in to youtube.com. I always clean cookies and data.
I only need this specific local-storage value in my browser. Is there any Firefox extension to make this possible?

Answer (score 2):

This greasemonkey script did the trick.

It re-creates the local-storage value everytime I load a youtube video page.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         YouTube Always 480p
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Always load youtube in 480p Quality
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.youtube.com/*
// @grant        none
// @run-at        document-start
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    localStorage.setItem('yt-player-quality',"{\"data\":\"large\",\"expiration\":1538037941852,\"creation\":1535445941852}")
})();
```